# Sum of a singular PSD matrix and a full rank indefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

Let's $A \in R^{n x n}$ singular PSD matrix, $B \in R^{n x n}$ full rank indefinite matrix and $C \in R^{n x n}$ full rank PSD matrix, I want to show that in order to fulfill the next equation:
$C=A+B$, $B$ must be PSD matrix.
I have an intuition behind that, but I can't prove it is correct (which I'm not sure 100%  it's correct).

My intuition is based on:
Let us assume that B hold a negative eigenvalue, and w.l.o.g let's
arrange the rows of the matrices by the size of the eigenvalues: $\lambda_1\le\lambda_2\le..\lambda_{n-1}\le\lambda_{n}$ hence we will have rows in C that will be negetive dominated or with a negative value on the diagonal, and C will not be a PSD matrix anymore.

Any Ideas? thoughts? if I'm in the right direction ? how to make it formal?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

No. this is false. Let $A$ be the identity. Then take $B$ to be $\epsilon$ times an arbitrary diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\pm 1.$ Then $A+B$ will be $PSD.$

**EDIT** You had asked for a singular $A,$ but the same example works - let $A$ be identity with one entry on the diagonal zeroed, and make sure that $B$ has a $1$ in that position.